# Objective-C method_exchangeImplementations is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to use the objc runtime library to swap method implementations. I have this simple example but it doesn't seem to work (the implementations are not swapped). What have I forgotten?

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "MainViewController.h"
    #import <objc/runtime.h>

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        //lowercase NSString Method
        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(lowercaseString));
        //uppercase NSString Method
        Method swappedMethod = class_getClassMethod([NSString class], @selector(uppercaseString));
        //swap em
        method_exchangeImplementations(swappedMethod, originalMethod);

        NSLog(@"%@",[@"test" lowercaseString]); //OUTPUT: test !!
        ...
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-upperCaseString` is an instance method, not a class method. So your call here:

```
Method swappedMethod = class_getClassMethod([NSString class], @selector(uppercaseString));
```

is likely returning nil. I'm not sure what `method_exchangeImplementations` does when one of the arguments is nil, but it's probably not what you're hoping for in any case.

Comment: Your absolutely right. It was a type-o. I meant to be using class_getInstanceMethod in both cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
the selector wasn't valid, I had to add a `.class` call.

```
class_getClassMethod(self.class, @selector(imageNamed:));
```

Comment: 'class()' is unavailable in Swift: use 'self' instead...is what the compiler says...which isn't very helpful also.